# OpenDJ silent install

Tags: opendj

I am writing a shell script that will read OpenDJ installation properties from a file and install OpenDJ.
I have read their documentation and prepared the properties file with required data.

```
hostname=punvm-core06.sigmasys.net
ldapPort=1389
generateSelfSignedCertficiate=true
#no-prompt=true
#enableStartTLS = true
#ldapsPort = 1636
jmxPort=1689
adminConnectorPort=4444
rootUserDN=cn=Directory Manager
rootUserPassword=ldappass
baseDN=dc=myldap
skipPortCheck=true
doNotStart=true
#usePkcs11Keystore = true
#keyStorePassword = password
```

When I run command from opendj unzipped setup it prompts me for license agreement to accpet even after putting --no-promt option i.e -n .

```
./setup -n -i --propertiesFilePath openDJ.properties
```

Due to this my installation does not proceed. What am i missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer , there is paramter called --acceptLicense that can be passed. Thier use manual is bit unreadable form i missed it.

Answer (score 0):

If documentation is unclear, you should create a ticket for improvement on the OpenDJ project issue tracking system